# how to interpolate color of an line drew using midpoint algorithm

Tags: opengl, graphics

I'm currently trying to implement a graphics pipeline on software level. Now I have implemented the midpoint algorithm to draw a line, but how should I interpolate color of pixels between two end points. I mean, I know the linear interpolation, but my problem is that the (x, y) coordinate of a pixel generated via midpoint algorithm is not accurately lying on the actual line defined by two end points. And I want to know how OpenGL deal with it.

Comment: Since the midpoint is trying to be quite close to the middle, wouldn't the average of the colors work? If not, how about calculating the distance from the calculated midpoint and both ends and make a weighted average based on that?

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'm not sure what you mean average of the colors. calculating the distance causes too much overhead.

Comment: If you have on one end the color `(a, b, c)` and on the other `(d, e, f)`, the exact midpoint color would be `((a+d)/2, (b+e)/2, (c+f)/2)`. Your calculated midpoint is not exactly the same as the real midpoint, but I would suspect the end result would still look pretty nice.

Comment: @Shahbaz I think you misunderstand it. the midpoint represents the center of a pixel not the middle point of a line.

Comment: Haha, sorry. I just guessed by the name of the algorithm. Can't understand how "a pixel" would have a center though, since it's supposed to be just a point.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know exactly how OpenGL handles color interpolation, but you could solve your problem by projecting the coordinates of the pixel (the midpoint) onto the line, and then calculate the color of the ***projected*** point by using linear interpolation on the colors of the endpoints of the line.

This is probably not the fastest method, but the result should be correct.

For information on how to project a point onto a line segment:
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Linear_Algebra/Orthogonal_Projection_Onto_a_Line